# Is is possible to read the built-in dictionary on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipados

I want to read the dictionaries installed (from Settings->General->Dictionary) on my iPad.
I know how to look up a word but not to read them page by page.

Could you please let me know how?

Answer (score 5):

From what I've been able to figure out, the "dictionaries" in iOS are for word definition lookup within iOS and in iOS apps and aren't in book (human-readable) format. Unfortunately, none of the dictionaries are available for reading as you would read a book.

Apple Books has many dictionaries available. Here are two from the top of the list:

[Webster's Unabridged Dictionary](https://books.apple.com/us/book/websters-unabridged-dictionary/id1042364712)

[Webster's American English Dictionary](https://books.apple.com/us/book/websters-american-english-dictionary-with/id1047122431)